# Fast point search in a stream of rectangles

Tags: java, algorithm, search

Here is the problem:

I have a stream of axis-aligned rectangles coming in described by their diagonal endpoints [x1,y1] and [x2,y2] where x1 < x2 and y1 < y2.

At some point, I'll get a point: [x,y]. I need to find all rectangles that contain this point.

What is the fastest way this can be done? I would like to optimize on the lookup time at the expense of insertion. Since it is a stream, I don't have to build this structure from scratch during lookup.

I am not sure if a range tree will be a fit for this since [x1,y1] and [x2,y2] are not independent.

EDIT: Note that, after I get the query, I will get more rectangles from the stream and then another query point and so on. Also, I may also be asked to disregard rectangles, so deletion should also be supported.
Bonus points if I can do it using existing Java libraries without having to implement my own interval/segment tree.

Comment: Does a rectangle contain points on its boundary?

Comment: Yes, points on the boundary are considered part of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify this problem by considering the two dimensions separately.

Build an ordered data structure that has an entry for each portion of the range so far that shares the same set of enclosing rectangle X dimension ranges. The split points will be values of x1 or x2 in the input so far. For each subrange, store the set of rectangles whose X dimension range covers that subrange.

Do the same thing for the Y dimension.

To look up [x, y], use binary search or similar to find the X dimension subrange that includes x, and the Y dimension subrange that includes y. The intersection of the sets of rectangles for those two subranges is the set of rectangles that each contains [x,y].

This is a rudimentary proof-of-concept implementation in Java, more as pseudo-code to clarify the idea than as a completed implementation. I have done very limited testing. I used an ArrayList to keep track of the ranges - a real implementation would be more likely to use some form of balanced tree.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class RectangleTest {
  RangeList xRanges = new RangeList();
  RangeList yRanges = new RangeList();


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RectangleTest rectangleTest = new RectangleTest();
    rectangleTest.test();
  }

  private void test() {
    Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[]{
        new Rectangle(2,100,4,102),
        new Rectangle(2,102,4,200),
    };
    add(rectangles[0]);
    add(rectangles[1]);
    testit(0,0);
    testit(3,101);
    testit(4,101);
    testit(4,102);
    delete(rectangles[0]);
    testit(3,101);
    testit(4,101);
    testit(4,102);
  }

  private void testit(int x, int y){
    System.out.println("("+x+","+y+") is in "+getRectangles(x,y));
  }

  void add(Rectangle rectangle) {
    System.out.println("Adding: "+rectangle);
    xRanges.addRectangle(rectangle.x1, rectangle.x2, rectangle);
    yRanges.addRectangle(rectangle.y1, rectangle.y2, rectangle);
  }

  void delete(Rectangle rectangle){
    System.out.println("Deleting: "+rectangle);
    xRanges.deleteRectangle(rectangle.x1, rectangle.x2, rectangle);
    yRanges.deleteRectangle(rectangle.y1, rectangle.y2, rectangle);
  }

  Set<Rectangle> getRectangles(int x, int y){
    Set<Rectangle> result = xRanges.lookup(x);
    result.retainAll(yRanges.lookup(y));
    return result;
  }
}

/* A Range represents a range of locations in one dimension, and
 * and associated set of rectangles.
 */
class Range {
  int start;
  Set<Rectangle> rectangles;

  Range(int start) {
    this(start, new HashSet<Rectangle>());
  }

  Range(int start, Set<Rectangle> rectangles) {
    this.start = start;
    this.rectangles = rectangles;
  }

  void add(Rectangle rectangle) {
    rectangles.add(rectangle);
  }

  void remove(Rectangle rectangle) {
    rectangles.remove(rectangle);
  }
}

/* A RangeList represents all ranges in one dimension.*/
class RangeList {
  List<Range> ranges = new ArrayList<Range>();
  static final int endAll = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

  RangeList() {
    ranges.add(new Range(0));
  }

  void addRectangle(int start, int end, Rectangle rectangle) {
    int startIndex = getIndex(start);
    Range startRange = ranges.get(startIndex);
    if (start > startRange.start) {
      // Need to split the start range
      startIndex++;
      ranges.add(startIndex, new Range(start, new HashSet<Rectangle>(
          startRange.rectangles)));
    }
    int endIndex = getIndex(end);
    Range endRange = ranges.get(endIndex);
    if (end > endRange.start) {
      // Need to split the end range
      ranges.add(endIndex + 1, new Range(end, new HashSet<Rectangle>(
          endRange.rectangles)));
    }
    // Add the rectangle to its ranges
    for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
      ranges.get(i).rectangles.add(rectangle);
    }

  }

  void deleteRectangle(int start, int end, Rectangle rectangle) {
    int startIndex = getIndex(start);
    int endIndex = getIndex(end);
    // Remove the rectangle from each range it is in
    for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
      ranges.get(i).rectangles.remove(rectangle);
    }
    // Merge ranges that now have equal rectangle sets
    for (int i = endIndex; i >= Math.max(startIndex, 1); i--) {
      if (ranges.get(i).rectangles.equals(ranges.get(i - 1).rectangles)) {
        ranges.remove(i);
      }
    }
  }

  Set<Rectangle> lookup(int location) {
    int index = getIndex(location);
    Range range = ranges.get(index);
    Set<Rectangle> result = new HashSet<Rectangle>(range.rectangles);
    if (location == range.start && index > 0) {
      // On the boundary, include ranges ending at location
      result.addAll(ranges.get(index - 1).rectangles);
    }
    return result;
  }

  /* Find the index of the range containing the location. For this
   * purpose only, ranges are treated as being closed on the left, open
   * on the right, so that every point is in exactly one range.
   */
  int getIndex(int location) {
    int rangeCount = ranges.size();
    if (rangeCount == 1) {
      return 0;
    }
    return getIndex(location, 0, rangeCount - 1);
  }

  /* Get the index of the range containing the location, as above, but
   * assuming the index is in [start,end]. Recursive binary search.
   */
  private int getIndex(int location, int start, int end) {
    if (start == end) {
      return start;
    }
    int mid = (start + end + 1) >>> 1;
    if (location < ranges.get(mid).start) {
      return getIndex(location, start, mid - 1);
    } else {
      return getIndex(location, mid, end);
    }
  }
}

class Rectangle {
  int x1;
  int y1;
  int x2;
  int y2;

  public Rectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + x1;
    result = prime * result + x2;
    result = prime * result + y1;
    result = prime * result + y2;
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (obj == null)
      return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    Rectangle other = (Rectangle) obj;
    if (x1 != other.x1)
      return false;
    if (x2 != other.x2)
      return false;
    if (y1 != other.y1)
      return false;
    if (y2 != other.y2)
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "[" + x1 + "," + y1 + "][" + x2 + "," + y2 + "]";
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to build the structure using an example? I didn't understand what you meant by: "Build an ordered data structure that has an entry for each portion of the range so far that shares the same set of enclosing rectangle X dimension ranges. The split points will be values of x1 or x2 in the input so far. " The range for the x and y dimension are 0->2^64-1 and they maybe be clustered in any way, so I can't divide the above range into uniform subranges. Note that I have made an edit to the question.

Comment: I'll work on expanding that part of my answer. Note that I said nothing about "uniform".

Comment: @user1715122 I tried to clarify in words, but decided showing it in code would be easier and more fun.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Insert and deletes are O(n), but lookups are O(logN+R) where R is set of output rectangles. I like the fact that I don't need to implement a BBST on my own to implement this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) is intended to effectively manage such queries

Comment: R-tree is primarily meant for storage on disk. Also, my query isn't a rectangle or a range, it is only a point for which I was thinking more along the lines of a dynamic interval tree.